# Looking for a flexible Reporting solution

Tags: open-source, reporting

I m looking at creative solutions for reporting, I have an app and now i need to create some reports from it.

I would be led to believe that the customer will be happy enough with excel reports, however what I want is that they have the freedom to create the reports themselves, without any help from development, so i need something simple yet powerful ( fun to work with would be a plus :) )

I use MS SQL Express.

Web or desktop deployment: it doesnt make any difference

Licensing costs Ideally none as its a very small operation

Open Source: preferred

Metadata modelling: none

Handle large amounts of data: not really, in the 100k records

large numbers of concurrent users: not really, 1 or 2 users

I remember I read about an csv solution somewhere but I cant remember if it came with a reporting engine of some sort

Thanks for your ideas

Comment: What constraints do you have?  Windows obviously, but are you looking for database support?  Web or desktop deployment?  Licensing costs?  Open Source?  Metadata modelling?  Handle large amounts of data?  large numbers of concurrent users?

Comment: Really good comments, editing

Answer (score 2):

Allowing users to generate their own reports would be wonderful, but for anything beyond a simple report, this quickly require basic database skills.  I've never seen a user-accessible report designer that users could actually design reports of any complexity with.

You're better off providing two things:

1. **The most obvious reports** with some filtering/sorting options.  Common ways to do this are with Crystal for a desktop app or SQL Server Reporting Services for a web app.
2. **The ability to export raw data** to Excel.  Office skills are far more common in most user groups than database skills.  Your users will have a better chance of creating a report with an Excel chart than they will have of working through any report designer I've ever seen.

Comment: I disagree. We have lots of customers (of Windward Reports) that are designed, with somewhat complex selects, by people with no DB or programming training. The trick is in the select wizard we created.